# Определить счет в футбольном матче

Tags: алгоритм, математика, любой-язык, теория, теория-вероятностей

Добрый день, пытаюсь решить задачу:

Мне нужно рассчитать вероятное количество **голов**, основываясь на доступной статистике команд.

Вот пример статистики:

```
0 => array(
    'name' => 'Бразилия', # название команды
    'games' => 104, # всего игр
    'win' => 70, # количество побед
    'draw' => 17, # количестве ничей
    'defeat' => 17, # количество поражений
    'goals' => array(
        'scored' => 221, # всего забито голов
        'skiped' => 102, # всего пропущено голов
    ),
),
1 => array(
    'name' => 'Германия / ФРГ',
    'games' => 106,
    'win' => 66,
    'draw' => 20,
    'defeat' => 20,
    'goals' => array(
        'scored' => 224,
        'skiped' => 121,
    ),
)
```

Это две команды. У нас в распоряжении количество игр, побед / поражений (винрейт). Плюс мы можем рассчитать среднее количество голов и пропусков.

Возможно ли, оперируя этими данными сделать примерный прогноз - **сколько голов** забьют команды друг другу?

На выходе хочу получить наиболее вероятный счет, типа: 0 - 2.

---

Я читал о распределении Пуассона, но там нужно высчитывать МЮ, а у меня не хватает для этого данных. :(

Comment: Если не важен язык программирования, то лучше поставьте метку «[любой язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA)» и уберите метки разных языков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень мало информации хранится в вашей базе данных. Чтобы хоть как-то угадывать исход нужно очень много подробностей матчей. (погода, соперник, у себя/в гостях, здоровье игроков) Когда соберёте всю информацию, и задача будет найти вероятность исхода *X*, то найти точную вероятность подробного исхода будет очень расплывчато. Подсказка: попробуй распределение Пуассона. Если есть статистика с соседом: забил **G** голов за матч с ним, то завтра результатом будет такое распределение: `M=G+1 D=2*(G+1) P(x)=(x+G)!/x!/G!/2^(x+G+1)`. Если в статистике **N** матчей с суммой всех голов **SG** то в среднем уменьшаются надежды и дисперсия. `M=(SG+1)/N D=(N+1)/(N^2)*(SG+1) P(x)=(x+SG)!/x!/SG!/((N+1)^(x+SG+1))*(N^(SG+1))`. Для справки при бесконечной статистике всё сводится к функции распределения Пуассона. `M=SG/N D=SG/N P(x)=((SG/N)^x)/(x!)*Exp(-SG/N)`.

Answer (score 1):

Нет,  этих данных явно недостаточно для определения вероятности победы.

В качестве простого примера - приведенные числа могут быть статистикой встреч с разными, непересекающимеся,  множествами команд.

О каком-то обоснованном результате можно говорить только при наличии статистики личных встреч.

Answer (score 0):

Придумать формулу - точно не получиться. Эта задача уже тысячи раз разобрана, описана и реализована. И выяснено, что "просто формулы" недостаточно. Для решения - хотя-бы немного отличающегося от подбрасывания монеты - необходимо задействовать практически всю мощь современного Data Sсienсe, включая Deep Learning в полной его красе. Хотите самостоятельно пройти путь первооткрывателей - это занятно, но бесперспективно.

Исходя из того, что вы уже не третьем форуме задаете этот вопрос - может быть стоило пока разобраться с "МЮ" - кстати, а что это такое? Кроме "Манчестер Юнайтед" ничего в голову не приходит. Или вы надеетесь, что где-то получите другой по-сути ответ?

Советую начать с ознакомления сначала с полупопулярной литературой, например

Н. Сильвер. «Сигнал и шум. Почему одни прогнозы сбываются, а другие – нет»

П. Флах _"Машинное обучение - наука и искусство построения алгоритмов"

посмотреть, что и как тот-же Нэт Сильвер делает на своем сайте http://fivethirtyeight.com/, а потом - постепенно погружаться в тему, изучать "как правильно оперировать данными" - а это наука, ее нахрапом не возьмешь. В противном случае рискуете остаться на уровне детских поделок, а не предсказаний.

Comment: Интересно, почему тот, кто ставит "минус" не находит нужным обосновать, с каким пунктом ответа он  несогласен?